# How to create an SQL column that can have multiple values?

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-database

I created a table in SQL using PostgreSQL called "tenants". Below is the code for the tenants:

```
create table tentants (
id bigserial not null primary key,
tenant_name varchar(1000) not null,
offices int not null,
number int not null,
email varchar(1000)
```

I want to include the ability to add multiple values to "office" in case a tenant rents more than one office. I don't want to use JSON for this. I tried creating a related table called "offices" but That could only allow me to add one office per tenant.
What is the best approach for this?

Comment: Create another table to store `(tenant, office)` pairs.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `"tenant_offices"` table (like you did before), having as structure :
`id, tenant_id, office_id,...` where `id` is the **primary key** of the `"tenant_offices"` table and `tenant_id` and `office_id` are **foreign keys**.

`tenant_id` which refers to your `tenants` table and `office_id` which refers to your `offices` table.

Here, the tenant can therefore rent several offices.

Hoping to have enlightened you, or helped !

Answer (score 0):

You can use **text**, that works for me with ids separated by commas like this

```
4,3,67,2
```

Anyway the proper approach would be another table and name it tenant_offices

```
tenant_offices
  columns >
    tenant_id
    office_id (well ofcourse you should have atleast an office table)
```

Comment: Suggesting a comma separated list is a **really**, really bad advice.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the relationship is one-to-many tenant to office (that is, office can be rented only by one tenant)

Then you have to create table offices with a foreign key that points to the tenant:

```
CREATE TABLE offices (
id bigserial not null primary key,
tenant_id bigserial foreign key references tenants(id))
additional columns if needed
```

note that in this version you will not retain history of rents (you will have to run update on offices to change tenant_id)

EDIT: In case of a many-to-many relationship (that will also allow us to retain history of rents) we need to create a relationship table:

```
CREATE TABLE TenantsOffices (
id bigserial not null primary key
tenant_id bigserial foreign key references tenants(id),
office_id bigserial foreign key references offices(id),
start_date datetime,
end_date datetime)
```

Useful information: https://www.sqlshack.com/learn-sql-types-of-relations/

Comment: What do you do if the relationship is many to many tentant to offices. Some offices might be in sharing and they split the payment.

Comment: In that case you have to move to a many-to-many relationship, I will edit the answer for this case